# Adding SQL layer with dropdown selector in Carto?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, carto, carto-js

I am trying to make a map that has a layer showing District boundaries of South Africa, with a selector allowing the user to view which climate change indicators are a priority to each District. Using [Carto's latest docs](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/guides/quickstart/#defining-layers) (with the Builder), I have successfully managed to build the foundation of my map and add the first layer of the District boundaries (see screenshot below):

[image: map sample]

Now I am trying to use the dropdown menu (id="selector") to search through a second dataset (called **indicators**) and fill the polygons that answer "yes" to the relevant feature column. Below is the database I created using QGIS:

[image: database sample]

Here is my code for the SQL layer:

```
    //Add SQL layer
    const indicatorsSource = new carto.source.SQL(`
      SELECT *
        FROM indicators WHERE selector ilike 'yes'
    `);
    const indicatorsStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(`
      #layer {
        polygon-fill: #162945;
        polygon-opacity: 0.5;
      }
    `);
    const indicators = new carto.layer.Layer(indicatorsSource, indicatorsStyle);

    //Add layers to map
    client.addLayers([boundaries, indicators]);
```

I think using "selector" in the SQL query is where I am going wrong.

The full code with a working SQL example can be viewed [here](https://codepen.io/JonoGIS/pen/vrexwp)

Comment: can you share a full code example? are you using a public or private dataset? and the correct API key?

Comment: I have added a link to the full code on CodePen at the end of my original post. I have changed the SQL query to use one of the layer's columns, just so you can see that it is currently working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an action to your dropdown object and use `setQuery` CARTO.js method to change the layer source as explained [in this example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-edit-sql-and-cartocss).

```
  const selector = $(".js-dropdown-selector");

  // change sql query with dropdown value
  selector.on('change', function(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    if (value == 'megacity') {
      source.setQuery(`SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places_simple where pop_max > 5000000`);
    } else {
      source.setQuery(`SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places_simple`);
    }
  });
```

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/0e911e3a8690de483854c197f908d087) you can check a working example.